# sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory

Tags: mount

I am trying to compile ARM code in Ubuntu 12.04.

Everything is working fine when I put my code in local directory. But when I put the code in cited mount directory this error happens:

```
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
```

Here is my mount command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=wx,passwd=wx,auto,nounix,noserverino,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=user,gid=users,noperm,rw,uid=1002,gid=1002 //192.165.54.18/prj_9330  /home/dongjw/work_dir/work_9330
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

What would cause this error?

Comment: Your working directory doesn't exist any more. Type `cd [PATH]` in your shell to go to an existing one.

Comment: also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593371/7111561

Answer (score 10):

### **I got this error using jshint through a python subprocess on Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit.**

```
node.js:464
var cwd = process.cwd();
                  ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
    at Function.resolveArgv0 (node.js:464:23)
    at startup (node.js:51:13)
    at node.js:555:3
```

It is caused because you deleted or moved a directory out from underneath it and the current directory can't be determined.

### How to tell if you are having this problem:

Run the command `cd .`   (If you get this error then you have this problem).

```
el@apollo:~/foo$ cd .
cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent 
directories: No such file or director
```

You tried to change directory into your current dir, and could not.

### How to reproduce the error:

jshint is affected by this error.  Make a directory `foo`, cd into it, make a file called `myjavascript.js`

```
cd /home/el
mkdir foo
cd foo
touch myjavascript.js
jshint myjavascript.js
```

jshint runs correctly, it says there are no errors which is correct.

Open a 2nd terminal, and `rm -rf` the directory `/home/el/foo` out from underneath.

```
rm -rf /home/el/foo
```

Run the `jshint myjavascript.js` again from your first terminal and you get an error:

```
el@apollo:~/foo$ jshint myjavascript.js 

    node.js:464
        var cwd = process.cwd();
                      ^
    Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
        at Function.resolveArgv0 (node.js:464:23)
        at startup (node.js:51:13)
        at node.js:555:3
```

The directory is gone!  And even if you were to replace it with the same contents, it has a different signature and the terminal can't recover, the method `getcwd` can't know what the current directory is.

### **Three Solutions:**

The terminal is confused about what the current directory is because its gone or it's signature has changed.  Do one of these to fix it:

1. Run the command `cd ..` until you stop getting errors.  This re synchronizes the terminal with the filesystem.  Then cd back into your directory.  Try again.  The error goes away.
2. Use `su youruser` in the terminal, enter the password.  It refreshes and brings you back to the same directory.
3. Close and reopen the terminal which flushes away the stale directory signatures.  Or send a nastymail to whatever program (jshint) or the thousands of other programs which can't tolerate or recover from stale directory signatures.

Comment: instead of running `cd ..` "often enough" you could also just `cd ~` directly to your homefolder

Comment: @Eric Leschinski I get this error sometimes on ubuntu 18.04 even when the folder is my home folder and has not been deleted, eg `ls .` works fine, etc. How do "directory signatures" work and what causes Ubuntu to get confused about the directory signature of a folder that has not been deleted?

Answer (score 5):

I get the same error, but I was trying to run a script in my home directory. I solved it with:

```
pushd ~ 1>/dev/null; pwd ; popd 1>/dev/null
```

This moves to my home directory, then runs `pwd` (but you can run anything that you like) and then the `popd` moves me back to where I was.  If you don't need to move back then:

```
cd; pwd
```

Would be enough to solve my problem.

The `1>/dev/null` parts are optional. I add them so that I can use the above line within a shell script without additional output that isn't needed in this case.

Comment: So that I can past this into a bash script and not end up with output that I don't want. I try to add as complete an answer as I can because when I find commandline-fu I find it easy to cut it down to my needs and I expect anyone that is using this to be a bit like me.

Comment: ok, I've added an edit explaining, (though some might feel that I'm teaching them to suck eggs - those that know do not need the edit and those that do not know can cut-n-paste, or look up that function that is not directly related to the original question.)

Comment: Sadly is like that :(

Answer (score 1):

Run the command in your home directory.
*Move to the home directory:*

```
cd ~
```

Then run the command again. That should help

Comment: Works for me in WSL ubuntu 22.04 lts

Answer (score -1):

Even i was having the same problem with python virtualenv.
It got corrected by a simple restart

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: I wouldn't think you would need to restart to fix it, just follow the other answers here, and `cd` to an existing directory.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/834914)

Comment: @N0rbert This is not a new question, it's clearly an attempt to answer and providing an IMHO valid (although surely not optimal) solution.

Comment: @ByteCommander I clicked this by mistake, I'm sorry.